# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListenersCountChangedListener"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have updated today Firestore dependency to the latest `19.0.0` version and I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListenersCountChangedListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebase-luwVSIdRPV8je9Y9uLU7Vw==/base.apk".

When trying to use:

```
db.collectionGroup("landmarks").whereEqualTo("type", "museum").get()
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What's the version of `firebase-core`?

Comment: Is firebase-core:16.0.8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the same problem as you. In the firebase release notes May 07, 2019 it says; "If you use Firebase Authentication, update to firebase-auth v17.0.0 or later to ensure functionality alignment with other updated Firebase libraries." So, I changed my firebase auth dependency to the latest version, which means;

com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0

and it fixed up my problem. I hope it helps. Best of luck! :)

[Also you can check the release notes from here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_may_07_2019)

Comment: I'm using com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0 and the problem still exists, any help

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I was using `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1`. I added the dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0` and it fixed the problem. It seems like a firebase auth dependency with version equal to or above version `17.0.0` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update all the dependencies to the latest version. Sync the project.. delete all the firebase import in every java file and re import..Then rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase storage or firebase database, and you got this error- then you have to change your dependency.

Change dependency version above or equal to 17, like below-

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
```